# Mongodump spontaneously failed: "error dumping metadata"

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

My remote mongodump backup script worked for months until today. I'm suddenly getting this error:

`Failed: error dumping metadata: error converting index (<nil>): conversion of BSON value '2' of type 'bson.Decimal128' not supported`

mongodump does not work on my remote backup server. However, when I run mongodump on the server when my production database lives, it works. But both servers use the exact same version of mongodump:

`mongodump version: r3.4.1
git version: 5e103c4f5583e2566a45d740225dc250baacfbd7
Go version: go1.7
   os: linux
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc`

The only place I've found any reference to this error is a Chinese blog (http://blog.5ibc.net/p/102326.html). However, their problem was that they were using an old version of mongo.

Does anyone know what went wrong or how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The versions of mongodump on the production server and the backup server were the same. However, my script was executing mongodump on the jump server that connects the backup server to the production server. And the jump server had an out of date version of mongo. I don't know why it failed yesterday after running for months. But it worked after updating mongo tools.